# Foci of Ellipse - given: Width and Height

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Can you help me out with the next problem.
I have an ellipse based on a width and a height. Is there any way you can find out where the focal points are?

I need this information because I need to know how long each radius is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The width of an ellipse is twice its semi-minor axis, $b$, and the length is twice its semi-major axis, $a$.

The distance from the focus, $F$, to the end of the semi-minor axis, $B$, is the same as the distance from the center of the ellipse, $O$, to the end of the semi-major axis, $A$.

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image]

The Pythagorean Theorem says that the distance from $O$ to $F$ is $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Focus) formula?

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the relevant parts of that link here; links can break, and in particular, Wikipedia may change so that the internal link may no longer be valid.

Comment: The thing is I don't have the minor and major radius. So I can't use the formula.

Comment: Excuse me, what are the wigth and the height then?

Comment: For example. 
You've got an ellipse in a rectangle with width s and height p. How can I express the place of the foci in s and p?

Comment: If ellipse and rectangle have four contact points: translate and maybe rotate an ellipse to situate its center in $(0,0)$, and  then $a = p / 2$, $b = s / 2$ (or vice versa). If you need positions of foci as vectors, make inverse translation and rotation. 
If there are less than four contact points, there are infinity of solutions.